# Wordpress menu and anchor links

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm having an issue with anchor links in my menu.

Here is a quick example of the issue I'm having:

The 2 Anchor Links:

```
<div id="anchor1"></div>
<div id="anchor2"></div>
```

The Menu:

Menu Item One (http://test.com/m1)

-Sub Menu Item One (/m1/#anchor1)

-Sub Menu Item Two (#anchor2)

Essentially Sub Menu Item One will bring me to the right place but it always re loads the page if I'm currently on it.

Sub Menu Item Two works perfectly if I'm on the page but does not work if I'm on another page.

So what I need is for the link to take me to the anchor location without refreshing the page if I'm currently on it and to take me to the anchor location if I'm on a different page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sub Menu Item One uses root-relative path `/m1/` so it changes current location, Sub Menu Item Two works only on current page __IF__ it has `#anchor2` HREF defined.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use full path in href on Sub Menu Item One? Add full path with the anchor in the end and it should work like you hoped.